# How to move logo on title page to right side in Torino/Beamer style?

Tags: beamer

I am using [Torino](https://github.com/bbatsov/beamer-torino-theme) beamer style to make a presentation in latex.

If one sets a parameter `titlepagelogo` to an existing image it appears to show that image as a logo on a front page but on a left side. Is there a way to move this logo to the right side?

```
\usetheme[pageofpages=/,% String used between the current page and the
                         % total page count.
          bullet=square,% Use circles instead of squares for bullets.
          titleline=true,% Show a line below the frame title.
          alternativetitlepage=true,% Use the fancy title page.
          titlepagelogo=sup1.jpg,% Logo for the first page.
          watermark= %loga/odwaga2,% Watermark/znak wodny uzywany na kazdej stronie-mozna zostawic pusty
          watermarkheight=60pt,% Height of the watermark.
          watermarkheightmult=6 % The watermark image is 8times bigger
                                % than watermarkheight.
          ]{Torino}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the whole Torino theme folder under another name (for example Torun), put this Torun folder at a place where you tex distro will find it (the best would be the appropriate subfolder from your personnal folder, texmf/tex/latex/beamer if you are using texlive), and finally change some lines in Torun's beamerinnerthemefancy.sty file. In the original file you have:

```
\begin{columns}
 \ifx\beamer@fancy@titlepagelogo\@empty%
      \column{\textwidth}
  \else
      \column{.5\textwidth}
          % Logo.
          \begin{centering}
              \vbox{}\vfill
              \includegraphics[height=.4\paperheight]{\beamer@fancy@titlepagelogo}
              \vfill
          \end{centering}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
   \fi
```

Change it to:

```
\begin{columns}
  \ifx\beamer@fancy@titlepagelogo\@empty%
      \column{\textwidth}
  \else
      \column{.5\textwidth}
      \column{.5\textwidth}
          % Logo.
          \begin{centering}
              \vbox{}\vfill
              \includegraphics[height=.4\paperheight]{\beamer@fancy@titlepagelogo}
              \vfill
          \end{centering}
   \fi
```

This should work (of course change Torino to Torun in your preamble). An even better thing to do would be to introduce a new option and submit it to the authors. I will try to create it.

Comment: I wanted to change the order of author with the logo - this does not work as I expected but now I know where to dig :) thanks

Comment: I've change the order of columns in that place :)

Comment: Also You don't Have to add Another Column. You can resize the size of the first one :)